# Webpack Never finishes

Tags: javascript, webpack, infinite-loop

I'm working on a React project and I suddenly realize that when I starting my server, webpack never finishes(CPU usage is full and no output prints on the screen from webpack, I check it with `-v` switch and nothing changed.

How should id find the problem, Since I am unable to get any usable information from npm/webpack.

**Edit:**

when running with production Configuration it works fine, But in Development Configuration, it never stops. blow is my dev/prod configuration:

**Dev:**

```
/**
 * DEVELOPMENT WEBPACK CONFIGURATION
 */

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const logger = require('../../server/logger');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const pkg = require(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'package.json'));
const dllPlugin = pkg.dllPlugin;

const plugins = [
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), // Tell webpack we want hot reloading
  new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inject: true, // Inject all files that are generated by webpack, e.g. bundle.js
    templateContent: templateContent(), // eslint-disable-line no-use-before-define
  }),
];

module.exports = require('./webpack.base.babel')({
  // Add hot reloading in development
  entry: [
    'script!jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    // 'script!materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js',
    'script!style/js/materialize.js',
    'script!style/js/init.js',
    'eventsource-polyfill', // Necessary for hot reloading with IE
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    path.join(process.cwd(), 'app/app.js'), // Start with js/app.js
  ],

  // Don't use hashes in dev mode for better performance
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
  },

  // Add development plugins
  plugins: dependencyHandlers().concat(plugins).concat(new CircularDependencyPlugin({
      // exclude detection of files based on a RegExp
      exclude: /a\.js/,
      // add errors to webpack instead of warnings
      failOnError: true
    })
  ), // eslint-disable-line no-use-before-define

  // Load the CSS in a style tag in development
  cssLoaders: 'style-loader!css-loader?localIdentName=[local]__[path][name]__[hash:base64:5]&importLoaders=1',

  // Tell babel that we want to hot-reload
  babelQuery: {
    presets: ['react-hmre'],
  },

  // Emit a source map for easier debugging
  // devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devtool: 'source-map',
});

/**
 * Select which plugins to use to optimize the bundle's handling of
 * third party dependencies.
 *
 * If there is a dllPlugin key on the project's package.json, the
 * Webpack DLL Plugin will be used.  Otherwise the CommonsChunkPlugin
 * will be used.
 *
 */
function dependencyHandlers() {
  // Don't do anything during the DLL Build step
  if (process.env.BUILDING_DLL) {
    return [];
  }

  // If the package.json does not have a dllPlugin property, use the CommonsChunkPlugin
  if (!dllPlugin) {
    return [
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        children: true,
        minChunks: 2,
        async: true,
      }),
    ];
  }

  const dllPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), dllPlugin.path || 'node_modules/react-boilerplate-dlls');

  /**
   * If DLLs aren't explicitly defined, we assume all production dependencies listed in package.json
   * Reminder: You need to exclude any server side dependencies by listing them in dllConfig.exclude
   *
   * @see https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/tree/master/docs/general/webpack.md
   */
  if (!dllPlugin.dlls) {
    const manifestPath = path.resolve(dllPath, 'reactBoilerplateDeps.json');

    if (!fs.existsSync(manifestPath)) {
      logger.error('The DLL manifest is missing. Please run `npm run build:dll`');
      process.exit(0);
    }

    return [
      new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
        context: process.cwd(),
        manifest: require(manifestPath), // eslint-disable-line global-require
      }),
    ];
  }

  // If DLLs are explicitly defined, we automatically create a DLLReferencePlugin for each of them.
  const dllManifests = Object.keys(dllPlugin.dlls).map((name) => path.join(dllPath, `/${name}.json`));

  return dllManifests.map((manifestPath) => {
    if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
      if (!fs.existsSync(manifestPath)) {
        logger.error(`The following Webpack DLL manifest is missing: ${path.basename(manifestPath)}`);
        logger.error(`Expected to find it in ${dllPath}`);
        logger.error('Please run: npm run build:dll');

        process.exit(0);
      }
    }

    return new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
      context: process.cwd(),
      manifest: require(manifestPath), // eslint-disable-line global-require
    });
  });
}

/**
 * We dynamically generate the HTML content in development so that the different
 * DLL Javascript files are loaded in script tags and available to our application.
 */
function templateContent() {
  const html = fs.readFileSync(
    path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'app/index.html')
  ).toString();

  if (!dllPlugin) {
    return html;
  }

  const doc = cheerio(html);
  const body = doc.find('body');
  const dllNames = !dllPlugin.dlls ? ['reactBoilerplateDeps'] : Object.keys(dllPlugin.dlls);

  dllNames.forEach((dllName) => body.append(`<script data-dll='true' src='/${dllName}.dll.js'></script>`));

  return doc.toString();
}
```

**Prod:**

```
// Important modules this config uses
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const OfflinePlugin = require('offline-plugin');

module.exports = require('./webpack.base.babel')({
  // In production, we skip all hot-reloading stuff
  entry: [
    'script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    // 'script!materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js',
    'script!style/js/materialize.min.js',
    'script!style/js/init.js',
    path.join(process.cwd(), 'app/app.js'),
  ],

  // Utilize long-term caching by adding content hashes (not compilation hashes) to compiled assets
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js',
  },

  // We use ExtractTextPlugin so we get a separate CSS file instead
  // of the CSS being in the JS and injected as a style tag
  cssLoaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
    loader: 'css-loader?modules&-autoprefixer&importLoaders=1!postcss-loader',
  }),

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      children: true,
      minChunks: 2,
      async: true,
    }),

    // OccurrenceOrderPlugin is needed for long-term caching to work properly.
    // See http://mxs.is/googmv
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(true),

    // Merge all duplicate modules
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),

    // Minify and optimize the JavaScript
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false, // ...but do not show warnings in the console (there is a lot of them)
      },
    }),

    // Minify and optimize the index.html
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
      },
      inject: true,
    }),

    // Extract the CSS into a separate file
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[contenthash].css'),

    // Put it in the end to capture all the HtmlWebpackPlugin's
    // assets manipulations and do leak its manipulations to HtmlWebpackPlugin
    new OfflinePlugin({
      relativePaths: false,
      publicPath: '/',

      // No need to cache .htaccess. See http://mxs.is/googmp,
      // this is applied before any match in `caches` section
      excludes: ['.htaccess'],

      caches: {
        main: [':rest:'],

        // All chunks marked as `additional`, loaded after main section
        // and do not prevent SW to install. Change to `optional` if
        // do not want them to be preloaded at all (cached only when first loaded)
        additional: ['*.chunk.js'],
      },

      // Removes warning for about `additional` section usage
      safeToUseOptionalCaches: true,

      AppCache: false,
    }),
  ],
});
```